# Count item tags from RSS feed (without knowing tag name)

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I'd like to get all used tags (in $feed->channel->item) from the rss feed without knowing the actual tag name. Yes, maybe this sounds weird, let me explain.

**Example**

```
<item>
    <title>Inademen van bloem kan astma veroorzaken</title>
    <link>http://www.nu.nl/gezondheid/3872032/inademen-van-bloem-kan-astma-veroorzaken.html</link>
    <description>Het keer op keer inademen van het fijne stof dat afkomstig is van het bakmeel bloem, kan astma veroorzaken. </description>
</item>
<item>
    <title>Inademen van bloem kan astma veroorzaken</title>
    <link>http://www.nu.nl/gezondheid/3872032/inademen-van-bloem-kan-astma-veroorzaken.html</link>
    <description>Het keer op keer inademen van het fijne stof dat afkomstig is van het bakmeel bloem, kan astma veroorzaken. </description>
    <test>Testing!</pubDate>
</item>
```

What I would like to achieve (sample script output for the above XML):

- Tag `<title>` used 2 times
- Tag `<link>` used 2 times
- Tag `<description>` used 2 times
- Tag `<test>` used 1 times

How can I do this? I could coun't all tags easily when I already know the tag name, but how to count them without knowing what tags are being used within `<item>`?

At the moment my script simply loads the feed and loop through/display the items:

```
<?php
getFeed('http://www.nu.nl/feeds/rss/gezondheid.rss');

function getFeed($feedUrl) {

    $feedUrl = file_get_contents($feedUrl);
    $feedXml = new SimpleXmlElement($feedUrl);
    $itemTags = array();

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($feedXml->channel->item as $item) {
        echo "<li><a href='$item->link'>" . $item->title . "</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: your url is inaccessible (sometimes)

Comment: Do you mean the RSS URL (nu.nl)? It should be working. However it's not important for my question, any RSS URL should do.

Comment: when i was testing sometimes its down, anyway, you can kindly check out my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can gete the name of the node using `->getName` method. Push them all inside an array, then use `array_count_values()`.

Example:

```
$url = 'http://www.nu.nl/feeds/rss/gezondheid.rss';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$tags = array();
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $children = $item->children(); // get all children of each item tag
    foreach ($children as $node) {
        $tags[] = $node->getName(); // get the node name of each children
    }
}

$count = array_count_values($tags); // count the values
echo '<pre>';
print_r($count);
```

Should output something like this:

```
Array
(
    [title] => 10
    [link] => 10
    [guid] => 10
    [description] => 10
    [pubDate] => 10
    [category] => 10
    [enclosure] => 10
    [copyrightPhoto] => 10
    [related] => 6
)
```

Comment: This is great, exactly what I'm looking for and easy to understand.